# Method not receiving attributes from shortcode call, general OOP problems

Tags: plugin-development, oop

The method `OpenMods` that you see below, is supposed to take an array generated by an `fgetcsv` function, and put it into an HTML table. `__construct` is supposed to, as is typically the case, define the attributes for the class, and `shortcode` is supposed to take two attributes from the shortcode, and if mods comes back, it is supposed to call another function in the class.

`OpenMods` did function when it was outside of a class, without the class attribute calls, so I'm fairly certain that isn't the source of my problem. My problem most likely lies within `__construct` and `shortcode`; However please don't overlook OpenMods as it may contain errors that are contributing to the problem, I'm just giving my estimation which isn't worth much since I'm having to ask to for help.

This is an example of the shortcode I'm trying to make work:

```
[priceguide file=’test.csv’ type=’mods’]
```

---

```
class CsvImporter
{   
    private $parse_header;
    private $header;
    private $delimiter;
    private $length;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
function __construct($parse_header=false, $delimiter="\t", $length=8000)
 {
    add_shortcode( 'priceguide', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
    $this->parse_header = $parse_header;
    $this->delimiter = $delimiter;
    $this->length = $length;
}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
public function shortcode($atts) {
    $attributes = extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'file' => '',
        'type' => '',
    ), $atts ));
    if ($attributes['mods'])
    {
        $this->OpenMods($attributes['file']);
    }
}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    function OpenMods($file) {
    ob_start();
     $fp = fopen(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . $file , "r" );
    if ($this->parse_header)
    {
       $header = fgetcsv($fp, $this->length, $this->delimiter); 
    }
    // table header and search html
    echo('<input type="text" class="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">');
    echo('<br>');
    echo('<table id="table">    <tr class="hidden">
        <th><b>
            Name</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>
            Cheese</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>
            Price</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Vote</b>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>');
    // integer for drop down/price submit
    $a = 1;
    // set values for table data
    while ($header !== FALSE) {
        $name = $header[0];
        $quanid = $header[2];
        $table = $header[3];
        unset($header[2]);
        unset($header[3]);
        $cssId = 'row-'.$a;
        $a++;
        //generate HTML
        echo('<tr>');
        foreach ($header as $index=>$val) {
            echo('<td>');
            echo htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo('</td>');  
        }
        // query to get item prices
        $sql = "SELECT ItemID, Price 
        FROM {$table}
        WHERE ItemID = %d
        GROUP BY Price
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1";
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $quanid));
        // put the results in the table
        echo('<td>');
        print_r($results);
        echo('</td>');
        // HTML for hidden row/price submission
        echo('<td>
            <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="' . $cssId . '">Vote</button>
        </td>');
        echo('</tr>');
        echo('<tr class="cat' . $cssId . ' hidden" style="display:none">');
        echo('<td colspan="4" style="white-space: nowrap">Enter ' . $name . ' Price:
        <form action="" name="form' . $quanid . '" method="post"><input type="text" id="' . $quanid . '" maxlength="4" name="' . $quanid . '" value="price_input" class="input" />
        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></form>
        <?php
  ?>
        </td>
        </tr>');
        wp_nonce_field('price_input');
    }
    echo("</table>");
    fclose($fp);
    return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for downvoting rather than commenting or answering. Very helpful.

Comment: It is would also very helpful if you give some feedback to the answers. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to initiate the class, something like:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

     $CsvImporter = new CsvImporter;

} );
```

Also, you are using `extract()` wrong; `extract()` won't build `$attributes` as an array. Anyway, `extract()` is not recommended any more and you should avoid using it. Also, note taht `if ($attributes['mods'])` should be `if ($attributes['type'] == 'mods')` as `mods` is not a valid index in `$attributes` array but the value of `type` index. Additionally you need to `return` a value int he shortcode callback.

I've tested this shortcode `[priceguide file="test.csv" type="mods"]` and it is working with the code bellow (note also that I've change `’` character in the shortcode, not sure if `’` is a valid value delimiter).

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

     $CsvImporter = new CsvImporter;

} );

class CsvImporter {   
    private $parse_header;
    private $header;
    private $delimiter;
    private $length;

    function __construct($parse_header=false, $delimiter="\t", $length=8000) {
        add_shortcode( 'priceguide', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
        $this->parse_header = $parse_header;
        $this->delimiter = $delimiter;
        $this->length = $length;
    }

    public function shortcode($atts) {
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
           'file' => '',
           'type' => '',
        ), $atts );

        if ( $attributes['type'] == "mods" ) {
            return $this->OpenMods($attributes['file']);
        }
    }

    function OpenMods($file) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

PD: While developing you should have [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) set to on and display errors set to on also; this way you would had seen a warning message saying that `$attributes['mods']` is not set.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I discovered that I was not creating an instance of the object, so I added this code: `add_action('init', 'my_init');
global $CsvImporter;

function my_init() {
    global $CsvImporter;
    $CsvImporter = new CsvImporter();`. However, now that the shortcode function is being initialized, it still isn't performing as intended, I added a simple `return 'test';` to the function on the first line to see if it worked, and it prints to the page, so there must be something still wrong with how I'm parsing the attributes and passing them to `OpenMods`.

Comment: I have also tried adding `return $attributes;` after I extract them, and it prints 2 on the page.

Comment: I just noticed one more error in your code: using `extract()` incorrectly. Answer edited and sample wokring code added.

Comment: Answer updated again.

Comment: Function `OpenMods` is now returning test with the code you supplied, however with my own code, it eats up server memory and gives me an error: `Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: That is another question not related with passing attributes from shortcode to object method, which is your question here. Post anohter question about that. Anyway, I'm not sure if that problem about output buffering is better for StackOverflow thatn WPSE as it doesn't seem specifically related with WordPress. Most of times I've seen that error is because there is not enough memory for the buffer. If it works fine without `ob_*` functions it is probably because of that.

Answer (score -1):

You may always need to check initation for the class to be called which seems to be your problem. In your case you can always simply call the class when included like below:

```
$csvImporter = new CsvImporter($parse_header, $delimiter, $length);
```

Or if you adding the class into the WordPress init hook such as a plugin format.

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'CsvImporter'));
```

Also note that if the class already exists you may want to do a simply check using the function function_exists to see if it is already being called.

Comment: Using `$this` in `add_action('init', array($this, 'CsvImporter'));` will fail. Using `function_exists` to check if a class has been initiaded won't work.